# PHP return array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have started to learn a mvc pattern and got simple example. But I can't manage to display data from mysql with return.

Here in this code is 3 examples(right now trying to figure out how and why.)

```
    public function getPostsList()
{
    // get data from database

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM visitors LIMIT 5");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    // Checking if my array works fine. And it works. (Check result 1.)

    $visitors = array();
    foreach($result as $user) {
     $visitors[] = $user;
    }

    print_r($visitors);

    // Trying to return my array (Don't work. See result 2.)

    return $visitors;

   // This is how data are shown in example (Line one ("Jungle Book" works. See result 3.)

    return array(
                 "Jungle Book" => new Book($visitors[3]['id'], $visitors[3]['ip'], $visitors[3]['date']),
                 "Moonwalker" => new Book("Moonwalker", "J. Walker", ""),
                 "PHP for Dummies" => new Book("PHP for Dummies", "Some Smart Guy", "")
         );


}
```

Result 1:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [ip] => 217.166.253.194 [1] => 217.166.253.194 [date] => 2018-06-01 16:52:27 [2] => 2018-06-01 16:52:27 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [0] => 2 [ip] => 66.249.92.20 [1] => 66.249.92.20 [date] => 2018-06-01 16:52:52 [2] => 2018-06-01 16:52:52 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [0] => 3 [ip] => 217.166.253.194 [1] => 217.166.253.194 [date] => 2018-06-01 17:00:14 [2] => 2018-06-01 17:00:14 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [0] => 4 [ip] => 217.166.253.194 [1] => 217.166.253.194 [date] => 2018-06-01 17:01:46 [2] => 2018-06-01 17:01:46 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [0] => 5 [ip] => 217.166.253.194 [1] => 217.166.253.194 [date] => 2018-06-01 18:31:47 [2] => 2018-06-01 18:31:47 ) )

Result 2:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in 
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\view\booklist.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\view\booklist.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'ip' of non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\view\booklist.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'date' of non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\view\booklist.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\view\booklist.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\view\booklist.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'ip' of non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\view\booklist.php on line 12
>
> Notice: Trying to get property 'date' of non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\view\booklist.php on line 12

Result 3:

> Title Author  Description
>
> 4 217.166.253.194 2018-06-01 17:01:46
>
> Moonwalker    J. Walker
>
> PHP for Dummies   Some Smart Guy

Result 4 (var_dump)

> array(5) { [0]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1"
>   ["ip"]=> string(15) "217.166.253.194" [1]=> string(15)
>   "217.166.253.194" ["date"]=> string(19) "2018-06-01 16:52:27" [2]=>
>   string(19) "2018-06-01 16:52:27" } [1]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1)
>   "2" [0]=> string(1) "2" ["ip"]=> string(12) "66.249.92.20" [1]=>
>   string(12) "66.249.92.20" ["date"]=> string(19) "2018-06-01 16:52:52"
>   [2]=> string(19) "2018-06-01 16:52:52" } [2]=> array(6) { ["id"]=>
>   string(1) "3" [0]=> string(1) "3" ["ip"]=> string(15)
>   "217.166.253.194" [1]=> string(15) "217.166.253.194" ["date"]=>
>   string(19) "2018-06-01 17:00:14" [2]=> string(19) "2018-06-01
>   17:00:14" } [3]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" [0]=> string(1)
>   "4" ["ip"]=> string(15) "217.166.253.194" [1]=> string(15)
>   "217.166.253.194" ["date"]=> string(19) "2018-06-01 17:01:46" [2]=>
>   string(19) "2018-06-01 17:01:46" } [4]=> array(6) { ["id"]=> string(1)
>   "5" [0]=> string(1) "5" ["ip"]=> string(15) "217.166.253.194" [1]=>
>   string(15) "217.166.253.194" ["date"]=> string(19) "2018-06-01
>   18:31:47" [2]=> string(19) "2018-06-01 18:31:47" } }

booklist.php

```
    <?php

    foreach ($books as $title => $book)
    {
        echo '<tr><td><a href="index.php?book='.$book->id.'">'.$book->id.'</a></td><td>'.$book->ip.'</td><td>'.$book->date.'</td></tr>';
    }

?>
```

Book Class

```
    <?php

require_once('controller/Config.php');

class Book {
    public $id;
    public $ip;
    public $date;

    public function __construct($id, $ip, $date)
    {
      $this->id = $id;
        $this->ip = $ip;
        $this->date = $date;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you share your result about `var_dump($visitors)`?

Comment: @Dorado Edited post

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from booklist.php? I'm going to guess that you need to add another foreach to your loop, since there's an array within an array.

Comment: Are you sure those results are correct? Esp. Result 2 (which should be the same as Result 1)

Comment: In booklist.php at line no. 12, you are trying to access property id with arrow, its not object, its array, so try accessing it with [`id`] instead of ->id. 
This might help.

Comment: Added booklist.php and book model

Comment: @YogeshSalvi Your anwser works. Thanks mate! Was struggling with this a lot.

Comment: Can I post this as answer, you can accept it?

Comment: @YogeshSalvi Yes. If you could add extra info about this I would be very happy to understand better this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In booklist.php at line no. 12, you are trying to access property `id` with arrow, its not object, its array, so try accessing it with `['id']` instead of `->id`. This might help.